# How to add Phonegap plugins for windows phone in visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cordova, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to add a barcode scanner plugin to my phonegap/cordova project for windows phone. I searched a lot but couldnt find any docs on adding external plugins to visual studio. I am using 'Visual studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone'. I got the phonegap plugin from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/WindowsPhone/BarcodeScanner). Even thought the plugin is depreciated, I had success in using it in eclipse for building the android version.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) out or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757051.aspx)

> Application developers use the CLI's plugin add command (discussed in The Command-Line Interface) to apply a plugin to a project. The argument to that command is the URL for a git repository containing the plugin code.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap-WP7 maintains the plugability of other platforms via a command pattern, to allow developers to add functionality with minimal fuss, simply define your C# class in the WP7GapClassLib.PhoneGap.Commands namespace and derive your class from BaseCommand.

For .cs file you just need to add it to your VS project

For .js file you need to add it to correct folder (to be a part of VS project), for example to 'www' and THEN add reference to this .js file in your html page (this step seems to be missed in your case).
Optional. For some libraries you will also need to add additional dlls, but you can't miss this step since there will be compilation issues.

Hope this help u